# How to build multiple src.rpm packages

Tags: build, mocking, rpm, yum, satellite

I want to build packages from http://ftp.redhat.com/redhat/linux/enterprise/7Server/en/SATELLITE/SRPMS/ but some of them have dependencies to each other. Is there any way to solve in what order should I build them? I am using mock for package building.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
# dnf install mock
# mockchain --recurse *.src.rpm
```

Answer (score 0):

Just point mock to all packages. Mock solves it itself.